# Please am trying to use phpmailer to send mail but keep getting smtp connect() failed tried settig the php.ini config and sendmail.ini

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

here is my code

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer();

//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();

    //Enable SMTP debugging
    //SMTP::DEBUG_OFF = off (for production use)
    //SMTP::DEBUG_CLIENT = client messages
    //SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER = client and server messages
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
    
    //Set the hostname of the mail server
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    //Use `$mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');`
    //if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6,
    //though this may cause issues with TLS
    //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
    $mail->Port =587;
    //Set the encryption mechanism to use - STARTTLS or SMTPS
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    //Whether to use SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    
    //Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
    $mail->Username = 'eliteiv@gmail.com';
    //Password to use for SMTP authentication
    $mail->Password = 'password';
    
    //Set who the message is to be sent from
    $mail->setFrom('eliteiv@gmail.com', 'First Last');
    
    //Set an alternative reply-to address
    $mail->addReplyTo('eliteiv@gmail.com', 'First Last');
    
    //Set who the message is to be sent to
    $mail->addAddress('eliteiv@gmail.com', 'John Doe');
    
    //Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
    //convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
        $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
        $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
    
    //send the message, check for errors
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message sent!';
        //Section 2: IMAP
        //Uncomment these to save your message in the 'Sent Mail' folder.
        #if (save_mail($mail)) {
        #    echo "Message saved!";
        #}
    }
    $mail->smtpClose();
```

Comment: What happened when you [searched for that error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=phpmailer+smtp+connect%28%29+failed), or read [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) you were given a link to?

Comment: Checked it out. Used composer to install, openssl  in php.ini is open. But i have not tried checking if the DNS is working. Please i have no idea what that is. Newbie @brombeer

Comment: I only fixed the formatting, I guess that comment was addressed at @Synchro

Comment: All the more reason to search and read - that’s how you learn. This question has been asked and answered hundreds of times, so there is a ton of things you can try without having to wait for yet another duplicate answer.

Comment: @Synchro thanks I've been trying and checking since yesterday. But I'll continue tho. Saw an answer to comment out isSTML..il see if that works(although i dont feel that's a good solution). But i feel that will work since mail() works

Comment: You've not included enough information here for *anyone* to answer. Post your debug output in your question.